# ElasticSearch APM Agents setup to Node Application

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, apm

I'm trying to integrate my Node.js Application with Elasticsearch and Kibana.Also i'm new to ElasticSearch.When i trying to install `npm install elastic-apm-node --save`,im getting bellow error.

```
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack ZlibError: zlib: Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLmU4.png)